# MongoDB aggregation to dynamically remove fields with an array of field names and by type

Tags: mongodb

If I have a mongodb document like this

```
{
    field1: 'one',
    field2: 'two',
    field3: 'three',
    rm: [ 'field1', 'field2' ]
}
```

Is it possible to have an aggregation pipeline that removes the fields whose names are contained within the `rm` array?  The result in this case would be this document

```
{
    field3: 'three',
    rm: ['field1', 'field2']
}
```

I'm also trying to conditionally remove fields by field type - in the example, would it be possible to remove all fields of type array without knowing the names of the array fields beforehand?

I have tried every combination of `$unset` and `$project` with `$unsetField` and `$$REMOVE` I can think of but no joy - it feels like it might not be possible.  It would be easy to do this in application code but I need to have it within the aggregation pipeline query itself.

Any pointers gratefully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `$$ROOT` document into array of kv tuples using `$objectToArray`. `$filter` the array with `$not` `$in` criteria and revert to original document form using `$arrayToObject`. Finally, `$replaceRoot` and `$merge` to update to the document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "kv": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
          },
          "as": "field",
          "cond": {
            "$not": {
              "$in": [
                "$$field.k",
                "$rm"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$kv"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a-JeyO_iCcg)